# React native doesn't play sound using Audiokit

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native, audiokit

Hello everyone I am new in Swift and really need any help. I am working on the music application therefore is crucial to reduce as much as possible a delay between a tap on a button and playing of sound. that is why I try to integrate my React-Native app with AudioKit using Native-Modules.
I used following example: [AudioKit Drums](https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/MiniApps/Drums.swift)

Here is my swift code:

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitEX
import AudioKitUI
import AVFoundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI


struct DrumSample {
    var name: String
    var fileName: String
    var midiNote: Int
    var audioFile: AVAudioFile?
    var color = UIColor.red

    init(_ prettyName: String, file: String, note: Int) {
        name = prettyName
        fileName = file
        midiNote = note

        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(
          forResource: "closed_hi_hat_F#1", withExtension: "wav"
      ) else { return }
        do {
            print("URL", url)
            audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        } catch {
            Log("Could not load: \(fileName)")
        }
    }
}
@objc(DrumsConductor)
class DrumsConductor: NSObject, ObservableObject, HasAudioEngine {
  // Mark Published so View updates label on changes
  @Published private(set) var lastPlayed: String = "None"

  let engine = AudioEngine()

  let drumSamples: [DrumSample] =
      [
          DrumSample("HI HAT", file: "closed_hi_hat_F#1.wav", note: 30),
      ]

  let drums = AppleSampler()

  @objc
  func playPad() {
      drums.play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(drumSamples[0].midiNote))
      let fileName = drumSamples[0].fileName
      print("fileName:", fileName)
      lastPlayed = fileName.components(separatedBy: "/").last!
  }

  override init() {
      engine.output = drums
      do {
          let files = drumSamples.map {
              $0.audioFile!
          }
          try drums.loadAudioFiles(files)

      } catch {
          Log("Files Didn't Load")
      }
  }
}
```

here is my Objective-C bridge:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(DrumsConductor, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(playPad)

@end
```

but when I call my DrumsConductor.playPad() from my JS code I don't hear any sound

File `closed_hi_hat_F#1.wav` is added to Resources folder.
I have tried to use library `react-native-sound` but it gives a significant delay between tap and playing sound.